# Where did the documentation beta go?

Tags: support, documentation

Since today, the [documentation beta URL](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com) redirects back to the Stack Overflow main page. It seems to be gone from my community list too. It doesn't seem to be integrated within Stack Overflow itself yet, nor I received any message while I did some contributions to it.

Where did Stack Overflow Documentation go?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the [PSA post](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/july-11th-announcements?noredirect=1) by [Kevin Montrose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80572/kevin-montrose), posted on Jul, 11th

> #### The Documentation Private Beta Is Coming To An End
>
> Sometime in the next week or so we'll be shutting down the docs-beta stack exchange, and migrating content over to Stack Overflow proper.
>
> Some quick details:
>
> - All "real" Documentation content will be migrated
>
>   - We won't migrate test tags or tags with just the default topic
> - At first, Documentation on Stack Overflow will be hidden from people who were not in docs-beta
>
>   - During this time reputation and profiles will be a little "weird" since bits will be hidden
> - Once we've "kicked the tires" enough on Stack Overflow, we'll announce the Documentation Public Beta and allow everyone in
>
> Moving to Stack Overflow isn't an end to Documentation development. I think, thanks largely to the participants in the private beta, we've polished the initial idea into a solid Google Beta™. We'll be fixing bugs and adding new features, big or small, for years to come.
>
> Some features we know we'll be working on:
>
> - Code blocks with multiple languages (think MSDN's C#/VB/F# switcher)
>     Mobile views
> - Embeddable topics and examples for 3rd parties
> - Improved search
>
> Get Excited!

Give it [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) for Documentation to appear on Stack Overflow proper ... ;)

Comment: And the header directly says that it is specifically this weekend: http://i.stack.imgur.com/i4g9C.png

Comment: In [this](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/questions/1615/data-migration-to-stack-overflow-happens-tomorrow?noredirect=1&lq=1) post, it is mentioned that data migration to SO happens today and the current plan is to re-enable it already on Monday for the private beta users. That post is the target of the link in the above provided screenshot.

Comment: @Matt Really? That would mean they break a tradition ;)

Comment: I knew about the meme and directly got what you meant. ;) Just wanted to add the reference and of course the screenshot with the nice *Documentation* tab... Only the unicorns know the exact time, so meanwhile, let's stick to *6 to 8 weeks*. I hope they will forgive the SE Team for working so hard on the weekend.

Comment: It isn't a proper Google Beta™ until they killed the service.

Comment: @PeeHaa I still miss Reader :(

Answer (score 19):

Documentation is now visible *for docs-beta participants* on Stack Overflow.  It won't be visible to everyone until we're done kicking the tires, so don't go nuts linking it externally or in answers just yet (it shouldn't be appearing in Google results either).  Contributing, committing to tags, and so on should be working fine - reputation and badges aren't enabled yet.

Aforementioned tire kicking shouldn't take too long, so expect the proper public beta to Start Soon™.  There'll be post in a couple different places, including MSO, when the public beta starts.

Comment: Did the goal of Docs ever get cleared up? I ended up not participating too much in the Beta after giving it a real stab because there seemed to be a real lack of consensus on the vision and no agreement on what was a good doc or a bad one. In the end if felt like it filled up with noddy  "programming 101" in different languages...